# Create video with multiple images and add fade in fade out animation using javacv library

Tags: android, ffmpeg, javacv

I am trying to create a video using multiple images which has some animation for each image. I am using javacv for this.

https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv

Till now I am managed to get frames from images and create a video from these frames.

Now I want to add some animation within the frames like fade in fade out animation.

Is there any solution for it?